# ISPConfig and Apache wildcard subdomains issue

Tags: apache

I own a VPS with ISPConfig installed. On that VPS we got 4 websites, which are running well, but we have recently spotted problem with Google indexing nonexistent subdomains.

No matter that if you type www.xxx.com or www.xxx.xxx.com or www.yyy.xxx.com  or yyy.xxxx.com it will load the main website www.xxx.com, which is, I assume, bad for Google as we give them millions of pages to index. I got to mention that subdomains "xxx" and "yyy" were not preset, in a matter of fact we got no subdomains at all, except "mail", which we use to reach the Roundcube for our websites.

I spotted that the "auto-subdomain" setting for every website is "*." and setted it to "www.", which fixed the issue with redirect but now all subdomains are still reachable - response code is 200 and they show empty pages.

I would like to show 404 error or something like that, not OK status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your dns manager, probably you have an "`*`" A record with `*.xxx.com` pointing to your IP address, then if you type `this.xxx.com` or `that.xxx.com`, you get `www.xxx.com`.